# Why else statement not working in discord js 14

Tags: discord.js

```js
if (!attach) {
  plr.send({
    content: `<@${plr.user.id}>`,
    embeds: [dmcontent]
  }).catch(async err => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log('test')
  })
}
```

Else statement not executing.

Comment: Is there an error being logged? And is there a reason for the callback to `catch` to be async?

Comment: @ZacAnger yes, it's hard to tell in the example but it's most likely the discord.js library's [`TextChannel.Send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/TextChannel) method, which is async.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @isaac.g for pointing out where this (probably) is in Discord.js. The code won't ever hit the `else` in your `.catch`, because if it hits the `catch` at all you should have an `err`. It's a dead branch of code, which could be replaced with just `.catch(console.error)`. It also doesn't look like there's any need for the callback to be an async function.

You can think of your logic in the `.catch` this way:

```js
try {
  throw Error('oh no')
} catch (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log('This branch will never get executed!')
  }
}
```